# How to Get the User Finger Print Bio Metric Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, bioinformatics, fingerprint

[image: FbF®mobileOne QuickDock]

I need to get the user finger print bio metric data using iPhone with the device which is i attached the links below. Although is it possible to get the bio metric data from iPhone using that device or Is there any other devices or technologies at market now for that. I've confused much about the topic on iOS. Please ping your valuable feedback if you had already known about it.
Thanks in advance.

[FbF®mobileOne QuickDock](http://www.fulcrumbiometrics.com/FbF-mobileOne-QuickDock-p/200102.htm)

[Nexa|Fingerprint™ – Fingerprint Recognition Software](https://www.aware.com/biometrics/nexa-fingerprint-recognition/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492705/ios8-get-fingerprint-data

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya & shallowThought
Please check the link. ( http://www.fulcrumbiometrics.com/FbF-mobileOne-QuickDock-p/200102.htm ) They are providing the device for get the finger print bio metric data. I agree your words. then how is it possible? could you please explain about it.

Comment: @Raja in ios this can not be possible to get bio matrix data because apple did not give authority to access those data

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it is asking how to use an add-on fingerprint scanner. It is, however, too broad and asking for off-site recommendations.

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya: Please don't discourage the people, They were new to the concept and want to get good a feedback from the good experienced people, so that they were posting to the question in stack overflow. But you simply telling that its a duplicate question, 

Actually he asked that he want to connect the biometric device with iPhone and he want to get the raw data from the biometric to iPhone,  Can you please tell me whether is possible in iPhone or not. If you dont know the answer please leave it.

Comment: @Vignesh and raja sorry its my miss understanding. your question now i got that you want to know to work with hardware right

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: Its okay man no issues.

Comment: Its okay @HimanshuMoradiya. YES, I want to connect the iPhone with the finger print scanning device (wired connection). And get the bio metric raw data from that device to my iPhone via coding. Is it possible? Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Have u achieved this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right you can't obtain fingerprint template (data) from embedded fingerprint sensor on iOS (on Android it's the same).

Only Solution is to add an accessory with a specific SDK.

Accessory embed a fingerprint sensor (hardware).
SDK (software) can communicate with fingerprint sensor.

Your solution is ok:
[FbF®mobileOne QuickDock](http://www.fulcrumbiometrics.com/FbF-mobileOne-QuickDock-p/200102.htm)

There's also this one for instance: [Tactivo mini for iOS](https://precisebiometrics.com/smart-card-reader/ios/)

Comment: Please accept if it's useful. I don't use tactivo device. I use this kind of tablet: https://www.morpho.com/en/biometric-terminals/mobile-terminals/morphotablet-2 with specific SDK to access embedded fingerprint sensor.

Comment: Sure It was really help full. I accepted. and one more question that does the device MorphoTablet™ 2  support on iPhone?

Comment: MorphotTablet is an Android device

Comment: There is any another Sdk for ios.