# Integrate fingerprint with remote login authentication

Tags: ios, fingerprint, localauthentication

I am aware how to use `LocalAuthentication` framework for authenticating a user in a app. What I have in mind is, how to integrate this with server login api ? From [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492705/ios8-get-fingerprint-data), I cannot get data of fingerprint. So firstly is it possible to use fingerprint for remote login authentication and if yes then how may I read fingerprint data (though it counter questions the given link) ?

Comment: you can use local auth to get data from keychain and proceed with login

Comment: @Lu_ : Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873688/save-data-in-keychain-only-accessible-with-touch-id-in-swift-3

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't allow to access the fingerprint data, that information is locked-down in the secure enclave.
What you CAN do is use the functions to authenticate the user returning `true` or `false` and sync this with the userid to your server.